# Can i run protractor e2e sanity testsuit from the UI by clicking html button

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, protractor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUJ0G.png)Req: Build one testing page (Using Html&css), where anyone can run the protractor test case by click on "run" button.
so I want to integrate HTML button with protractor script. plz, give me any lead on the solution.
(but dont want use php so can )

conf.js

```js
exports.config = {
    framework : "jasmine",
    directConnect: true,
    
        specs : [
            "./spec.js"
        ]
    };
```

spec.js

```js
describe('prot', function () {
    
    it('test', function () {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

       // element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    });
});
```

page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<button>Analytics Sanity</button>
<script src="server.js"></script>

</body>
```

server.js

```js
const shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('./bash.sh')
```

bash.sh

```css
#script1.sh
clear
echo "Starting shell script";
protractor conf.js
echo "ending of the script";
cat script1.sh
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples to show what you have tried and where you have problems. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what's wrong with jenkins?

Comment: I have to make one sanity portal there is only one HTML page to run all module sanity .that page consists of several buttons so I want to integrate automation script with these buttons. so the task is whenever I will click the button of HTML it will start the sanity automatically without opening any IDE.

Comment: I can use Jenkins but this portal should be useful for the non-technical person also so that he just open the page and click on the button, but maybe I am  wrong plz lead me according to best

Answer (score 0):

couldn't attach the image to the comments

this is what jenkins may look like

[image]

non technical people save the bookmark to the page, open it whenever need to run tests, specify all desired parameters from available dropdowns/inputs/checkboxes
and click `Build` button to run the tests

Reports are also available within the jenkins along with screenshots and video recordings. Capabilities include sending email or slack notifications, history of execution etc.

I think this covers what you need and much more and most of the functionality comes out of the box. For others, you just need to install existing jenkins plugins

Answer (score -1):

The method I've used to run the e2e protractor script using an html button is with the help of a HTA application